# Multiple users single device - Mobile PUSH

Tags: mobilepush, salesforcemobilesdk-ios, sfdcmobilesdk-android

I have a scenario, User A Logs out of the mobile app, and user B log-in the app using the same device. Then what will happen on the back end New Device ID will be created and assigned to User B or User A device ID will be transferred to User B?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multiple users on a single device is not a supported use-case, but to answer your question: `DeviceID` is static for the life of the installation.

Comment: Thank you so much Bill for the help here, It means Device ID will belong to the User B now and SDK will send an API to SFMC to remove the Device ID (Opt out or Delete) from USer A contact key and will assign it to the User B contact key?

Comment: No. {random text so I can submit this comment}

Comment: No same Device id will be assigned to newly logged-in customers.