# Mobilepush multiple users/contacts on a single device

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobilepush, mobilesdk

Our use case for the mpbilePush is to have multiple users/contacts associated with a single device.
This is due to our SF structure, where businesses and contacts can be listed with the same phone number. And also log in as different contacts to the App.

We will have separate contacts that have registered to use the Same Device.

I have not found any information about this in the documentation.

Can someone confirm that this is supported in MC?
And if not, what will happen when a new contact is registered to a device which has already been assigned to another contact?

The only information found is this:  [Multiple users single device - Mobile PUSH](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/388031/multiple-users-single-device-mobile-push)

But it's old and doesn't specify the outcome of registering another contact doesn't the same device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiple users on a single device is still not a supported use-case in MC. When a new contact is registered to the same device, old data (example : In-app messages, Inbox messages, etc) will still stay on device and will be displayed to the new contact.